# reference to local file is invalid

Tags: swift, wkwebview

This view is to display a local html file. When I launch it, the view never displays, the screen just hangs on the calling view.  The exception is a nil value for `let fileURL =`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:"about", ofType: "html")!)
        webView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
    }
}
```

[image: Adding about.html to project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t need to cast the `Bundle.main.path(forResource:"about", ofType: "html")` to `URL`. Do it like this instead:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "about", withExtension: "html")!
webView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
```

**Update:**
Remember to also add the file in your Project settings > Your project target > Build Phases > Copy bundle resources otherwise it won´t work. When you add the file to your project remeber to:

- Check "copy items if needed"
- Select "create folder references"

Comment: This change allowed the page to display, but the webview didn't display the local file.

Comment: FYI - you do want to force-unwrap the call to `Bundle.main.url/path`. Using optional binding is pointless in this case. If the file isn't there, you have a serious setup issue with your app during development. Once the file is setup properly, it will never fail so force-unwrapping is safe and much simpler.

Comment: @rmaddy, you´re right. Updated the post. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @RashwanL not yet. EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x104b53b54) reoccurred after adding the about.html file. I've added a graphic showing the added file in xcode, <noob>not sure why it's not being found</noob>

Comment: Did you do as I provided in the answer? [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1z77umn0s72b2j/WebView.zip?dl=0) is a test project were I do everything that is stated in my answer and it´s working. Download it and try it out. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you"ve been (sufficiently) helped.

Comment: Turns out that as coded, wkwebview has to be run for iOS 11 only. There it works. If you point the project at a lower iOS it fails with class not found.  That's a different topic, I've accepted your answer, thanks!

Comment: Great that you made it work. Good luck with your project @Alan